# Flexdashboard Gauge not rendering when I publish to shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard

This is the code that I am using to render a gauge in flexdashboard with a `runtime: shiny` :

```
`renderGauge({
        select <- reactive({
        input$select})
   call_data_f <- pbrCalls_Data %>%
        filter(pbrCalls_Data$village==select())
sum_table <- round(sum(call_data_f$status_match,na.rm = TRUE)/sum(complete.cases(call_data_f$status_match))*100)
gauge(sum_table, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
    success = c(75, 100), warning = c(40, 74), danger = c(0, 39)
  ))
})`
```

When I knit locally, the gauge appears correctly as shown below:

But after publishing to shinyapps.io, I can only see the 0, the %age and 100, no gauge:

Comment: You posted some server code here, still I cannot see any ui code. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: @nilsole on flexdashboard, I did not use the ui & server codes. I just have this wrapped in a r code chunk.

Comment: Well, this is hard to reproduce I guess. Have you tried to move `select <- reactive({input$select})` outside of the render function? Also, please consult the manual, pages 5-6 here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexdashboard/flexdashboard.pdf And another page here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html

Comment: Also, check the shinyapps.io error log.

Comment: Yes I tried all those, let me embed the code on the published app then share the link here.

Comment: @nilsole, check on the source code for this app, row 190 to 255, I have 4 gauges. https://jmunene.shinyapps.io/flex_app/

Comment: thx, will do in a couple of hours from now ... ;)