# Shiny App - googleAnalyticsR causing flexdashboard gauges to lose colors

Tags: r, google-analytics-api, shiny, flexdashboard

I am having a problem with my Shiny App, specifically a problem between [flexdashboard gauges](https://rdrr.io/cran/flexdashboard/man/gauge.html) and [googleAnalyticsR](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/shiny.html).

When I initially load the app with the values pre populated, the gauges appear with the appropriate color.
[image]

However, immediately after I log in and create my authorization token for Google Analytics (googleAuthR) the color on the gauge bars disappears.
[image]

Below is the stripped back version of the app I am working on which showcases this problem. I have tried multiple different methods of loading packages (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42363577/4648772), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39769646/4648772)), but I have had no luck. There are no errors in the Chrome or R console, so I am not sure why the Google Authentication would cause the graphs to lose their color, but not the values.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(googleAuthR)
library(flexdashboard)


ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Test", tabName = "Test", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Test",
              fluidRow(

                titlePanel("Test"),
                sidebarPanel(
                  helpText("Start by logging in to your Google Analytics account."),
                  googleAuthUI("login"),
                  br()
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  column( width = 4,
                          flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("outputBox1")
                  ),column( width = 4,
                            flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("outputBox2")
                  ),column( width = 4,
                            flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("outputBox3")
                  )
                )
              ))
      ))))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  token <- callModule(googleAuth, "login")


  output$outputBox1 <- renderGauge({ 
    flexdashboard::gauge(15.8513963, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
      success = c(71, 100), warning = c(39, 50), danger = c(0, 39)
    ))
  })
  output$outputBox2 <- renderGauge({ 
    flexdashboard::gauge(80.1935234, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
      success = c(71, 100), warning = c(39, 50), danger = c(0, 39)
    ))
  }) 
  output$outputBox3 <- renderGauge({ 
    flexdashboard::gauge(5.869565, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
      success = c(71, 100), warning = c(39, 50), danger = c(0, 39)
    ))

  }) 
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```